# Accessing linked SVG element with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this SVG included in my HTML

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 128.00456 127.33362" width="0" height="0" position="absolute">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="e" xlink:href="#b" patternTransform="matrix(1.006 0 0 1 288.184 313.89)"/>
    <pattern id="b" xlink:href="#c" patternTransform="matrix(1.006 0 0 1 -.206 0)"/>
    <pattern id="c" width="119.183" height="42.49" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="translate(288.338 309.89)">
      <path fill="none" id="circle-top-fill" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3.971" stroke-miterlimit="1" d="M2.614 39.184A62.015 62.015 0 0 1 59.83 1.987a62.015 62.015 0 0 1 56.752 37.9" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-dasharray="0.99275, 0.99275"/>
    </pattern>
    <path fill="url(#e)" d="M288.39 313.89v40.173h119.693V313.89H288.39z" id="circle-top" transform="translate(-283.99 -313.89)" />
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Then I use it in the page with

```
<svg class="circle">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#circle-top"/>
</svg>
```

Now I need to add different colors to it (eg. add class `.circle--blue` to `.circle`).

When I use

```
.circle--blue use #circle-top-fill {
  stroke: blue;
}
```

it doesn't work. Apparently `fill="url(#foo)"` doesn't create shadow DOM.

Is there any way to access `#circle-top-fill` when needed?

**TL;DR:** I have inline SVG definitions in my HTML. Then I want to use it on several places on the page with different colors.

**Edit:** [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mw0yhdyr/)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: That's not what use is for. If you want different images use javascript clone and adjust the clone.